# How to retrieve and pass data to child views of a tab bar controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

My app depends on some prerequisite data that needs to be pulled remotely.  The data retrieved is required by several child view controllers of my tabbarcontroller. I want to pass the retrieved data to these view controllers properties.

I know I can do the following:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController =
        (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController =
[tabBarController viewControllers][0];

MyViewController *myViewController =[navigationController viewControllers][0];
myViewController.prop = myVal;
```

My question is how I can handle this with the delay of a network call.  If I do this synchronously it will hold up the user.  If I pass the data asynchronously, I don't know if this being executed in the app delegate will respect the delay.

How could I carry out this workflow?

Is there an iOS best practices way to accomplish this use case?

Comment: You don't "pass the data asynchronously". You do the network call, the info is retrieved asynchronously, your code is notified, and if you need to pass it to someone else you do it on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You arrange to get a callback when the data is downloaded. When you get it, you do (on the main thread) whatever you want to do. For example, here's how I download and parse an RSS feed when my app launches:

```
- (void)doRefresh:(id)sender {
    FeedFetcher* ff = [FeedFetcher new];
    ff.delegate = self;
    [ff downloadAndParseRSS];
}
```

Now we are downloading and parsing in a background thread, so the user is not blocked. When it's all over, I am the delegate, so I get the callback:

```
- (void) downloadAndParseRSSSucceeded:(BOOL) ok
                         receivedData:(NSMutableData*) receivedData
                           parsedData:(FPFeed*) parsedData
                                error:(NSError*)err {
    // ... get onto main thread, do something with the data
}
```

If "do something with the data" involves getting a reference to another view controller and handing it some data, fine, no problem.

If, for example, you use the built-in NSURLSession stuff to do your "network call", all of that is handled perfectly coherently for you with lovely delegate callbacks (which can be on the main thread).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how I can handle this with the delay of a network call. If I do this synchronously it will hold up the user.

A good way to handle these things is to make sure that you have a clearly defined data model, and that all the view controllers that need access to the data in question have a reference to the model. Then you can have a background task request the data and update the model as the new data comes in. When the model is updated, post a notification that will tell any interested objects (in this case, your view controllers) that the model has changed.

To make things even more automatic, each view controller can use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to observe the parts of the model that it cares about, so that it only gets notified when things that affect it change.